# How to show td's border over tr's background color

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

Using html tables in Firefox 24 to display information, I extensively use CSS to format lines and columns.

The problem I encounter is that I specified some borders for `<td>`, and a `background-color` for `<tr>`, but the tr's background color overlaps the td's borders.
Is it normal than tr styles are shown on top of td's ones ?

The two problems are :

1. All the td's with `class="ref"` should correctly display a 2px right and left
   border in `.ann` and `.tbx` rows (which isn't the case when tr background color is set)
2. The first column right border should always be displayed too, even when the background color is set in the adjacent cells, cf.

   ```
   div.tb tr td:first-child {
       border-right: 1px solid black;
   }
   ```

Here is a code sample (http://jsfiddle.net/RVJSD/):

CSS:

```css
/* Default reset style sheet */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.tb {
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: right;
}

div.tb tr td {
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

div.tb tr td {
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

div.tb tr td:not(:first-child) {
    width: 92px;
}

div.tb tr td:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

div.tb tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:first-child):not(.ref) {
    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

div.tb tr td.ref { /* FIXME */
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

div.tb tr.ann {
    background: #99CCFF;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

div.tb tr.ann td {
    height: 2.5em;
}

div.tb tr.ann td:first-child {
    background: white;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
}

div.tb tr.ann td.ref {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}

div.tb tr.txb {
    background: #99CCFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="tb">
        <table>
            <thead/>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="ban"><td>Barfoo</td><td>Bar</td><td>Blah</td><td>Foobar</td><td>FooBlah</td><td>BlahBar</td><td>Foo</td></tr>
                <tr class="ann"><td>ann</td><td>13</td><td>9</td><td class="ref">13</td><td>12</td><td>9</td><td>15</td></tr>
                <tr class="nbr"><td>nbr</td><td>-34</td><td>20</td><td class="ref">15</td><td>18</td><td>123</td><td>12</td></tr>
                <tr class="txb"><td>txb</td><td>2,83%</td><td>3,38%</td><td class"ref">3,84%</td><td>3,21%</td><td>3,52%</td><td>3,27%</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

If possible, I'd like to keep the setting `border-collapse:collapse` (and not `separate`) like so :

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

and I don't like the [Table Border Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143445/table-border-overlap) solution as the div adds additional border width and make the code less legible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your stylesheet styles everything with `position: relative`.  This causes every cell to be its own stacking context and to paint its background and the background of its row and table over the borders of earlier cells if they overlap (which in the collapsed border model they do).  And since you're putting all the borders on the *right* of the cells (as in, depending on the border of the earlier cell showing through), things fail.

Note that per spec the behavior here is not undefined; CSS (as of version 2.1, at least) does not define what happens when you relatively position table cells.

Comment: Indeed, commenting out the `position: relative;` statement in the defaut reset style sheet displays correctly the borders. On the other hand, I guess that if most reset stylesheet uses `position: relative;` by default for all elements, shouldn't I keep it that way ? If so, I tried using `position: static;` on .td tr and td, without reproducing the corrected behavior. Any though on that ?

Comment: Why would reset stylesheets use `position: relative`?  `static` would make a lot more sense...  And if I style the tr/td in your case with `position:static`, the borders appear fine.

Comment: On http://jsfiddle.net/M25R7/ I added as you mentioned `position:static` to `div.tb tr` and `div.tb tr td`, keeping the `position: relative` for the `*` element. Unfortunately, borders aren't showing well. So far the only way to make it work is to just comment out the `position: relative` for `*`. Is that the only solution ?

Comment: You might need to statically-position the tbody too.

Comment: using `div.tb tbody,
div.tb tr,
div.tb tr td {
 position: static;
}` indeed resolve the problem, without having to comment out the `position: relative` for `*`. Thanks !

Answer (score -4):

Is this you looking for for hover use `:` instead of `.`

```
div.tb tr.ann td:hover { /* FIXME */
    background: #069D81;
    border-left: 2px dotted #069D81;
    border-right: 2px dotted #069D81;
}
```

**[Js FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RVJSD/2/)**

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question. No "hover" whatsoever